# Isn’t $(c^2 - v^2/c^2)^(1/2)$ the mathematical equivalent of $( 1 - v^2/c^2)^(1/2)$ ? Why do we never see it?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Isn’t  $\sqrt{c^2 - v^2/c^2} $ the mathematical equivalent of
$\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$?  Why do we never see it presented this way?

Comment: Did you make a typo? Did you mean to ask about $\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}$?

Comment: "Why do we never see it..." Who is "we"?

Comment: Do you understand that $c^2-v^2/c^2$ means $c^2-(v^2/c^2)$ and not $(c^2-v^2)/c^2$? Division has higher precedence than subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking why we never see $\sqrt{\frac{c^2-v^2}{c^2}}$ as opposed to $\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$?

If so, what advantage does the former have?  The latter expression makes it clear that the relevant quantity is $v/c$, which varies between 0 and 1. It's easier to expand in a Taylor series, it's easier to actually *compute* for any given value of $v$, it is *aesthetically* nicer to look at (at least to my eyes) ... It's hard for me to imagine why you'd prefer the former expression.

Comment: Thank you, J. Murray, for the most helpful response so far.  At least l know now my representation IS mathematically equivalent.  I now ask, for the novice - for whom elegant math is often opaque or intimidating - which form is more likely to convey the driving MOTIVE underlying the inquiry? In the former way the uninitiated can just glance at it and declare, “Oh,      it’s just the DIFFERENCE between some quantity and some set STANDARD over the STANDARD.  Can we never sacrifice  or subordinate elegance in the interest of pedagogy?

Comment: @RalphP. *l know now my representation IS mathematically equivalent* **No**. What *you* wrote is *not* equivalent, because you left out critical parentheses. What J. Murray wrote *is* equivalent because he corrected your mistake. Without the parentheses, what you wrote is in fact nonsense, because, as Dale correctly explained, it is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: @RalphP. I often find that elegance is best sacrificed in the interest of pedagogy. But in my opinion, this is not one of those times.  It's just as easy to glance at it and say "Oh, it's just one minus the quantity over the 'standard'"? And I'm not sure what motive you refer to - but in my opinion, relativity is best studied by carefully thinking through what each term means. It is not a subject which is at all accessible "at a glance," and somebody who thinks that it *is* has almost certainly made some grievous conceptual errors. So I don't mind students taking some extra time to think.

Answer (score 2):

You never see the first expression because it is dimensionally inconsistent. They are not equivalent

Comment: Isn’t the Lorentz-Fitzgerald contraction always written as (1 - v^2/c^2)^(1/2) ?

Comment: @RalphP.  :  The answer to any question of the form "Isn't X always written as Y?" is no.

Comment: @RalphP. It’s often written as $1/\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean $\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}$ or $(1/c)\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}$.

Frequently it is convenient to define $\beta = v/c$ so that the variables are dimensionless: $\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}$ is just a number without units, since $\beta$ is a ratio without units.

When you are too lazy to write $c$ and you set $c=1$ as physicists often do, you might write $\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}$ or $\sqrt{1-v^{2}}$ with the understanding that $v$ here is in units of c.

The Lorentz factor appears often in special relativity as $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}$ which gives this combination special importance. Most would not prefer to write $\gamma = \frac{c}{\sqrt{c^{2}-v^{2}}}$ instead, since writing "1" is so easy.